# Multi Databases in django: misplaced tables

Tags: django, database, postgresql, database-migration, multiple-databases

I have two postgres db in my project, one for every app: app1:Store, app2:Warehouse. Both of them have Order model which django names: store_order & warehouse_order (I am fine with that part);
But after migrations there is a problem, both store_order and warehouse_order got in warehouse_db, also all these django tables I want to be only in store_db:

[image: warehouse_db]
[image: store_db]

---

[**github repo**](https://github.com/GrailFinder/crestopher)

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {},
    'store': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'store_db',
        'PORT': 5432,
    },
    'warehouse': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'warehouse_db',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['warehouse.router.WarehouseRouter', 'store.router.StoreRouter']
```

warehouse/router.py

```
class WarehouseRouter:
    """
    A router to control operations in warehouse app
    """
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'warehouse':
            return 'warehouse'
        else:
            return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'warehouse':
            return 'warehouse'
        else:
            return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label == 'warehouse':
            return db == 'warehouse'
        return None
```

store/router.py

```
class StoreRouter:
    """
    A router to control operations in store app
    """
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        return 'store'

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        return 'store'

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        return True
```

warehouse/models.py also same as store/models.py except of app_label

```
class Order(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=False, unique=True, primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid1)
    amount = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    price = models.FloatField(null=False)
    comment = models.TextField(null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(null=False, auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.id}: {self.created_at}'

class Meta:
    app_label = 'warehouse'
```

I tried to be as close as possible to this [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/multi-db/#an-example)

and my migrations script

```
#!/bin/sh -

docker-compose run crestopher python manage.py makemigrations
docker-compose run crestopher python manage.py migrate --database=warehouse    
docker-compose run crestopher python manage.py migrate --database=store
```

I also tried to do makemigrations and migrate with one db and then with other, but result was the same.

---

### **EDIT**

I just run it again on the next day and got:

[image]
[image]

I don't understand why. I changed migrations script to:

```
#!/bin/sh -

docker-compose run crestopher python manage.py makemigrations warehouse
docker-compose run crestopher python manage.py migrate --database=warehouse

docker-compose run crestopher python manage.py makemigrations store
docker-compose run crestopher python manage.py migrate --database=store
```

but on the first day I run it about 1000 times without effect. I'll try to understand what is going on, also these default django tables still should be only in store db. I'll put an answer here if I'll find one.